# String#matchの正規表現にマッチした物が無い時に特殊変数に入る値について

Tags: ruby

文字列をマッチさせて数値に変換する時に

```
'10'.match(/(100)/){ $1 } # => nil
```

なので、`to_i`をつければ`0`を返してくるかと思ったのですが、変わらず`nil`を返してきます。

```
'10'.match(/(100)/){ $1.to_i } # => nil
```

不思議だったのでクラス名を取ろうと思ったのですが

```
'10'.match(/(100)/){ p $1.class } # => nil
```

でも何も返ってきません。
正規表現でマッチした値を返す `$1` などの特殊変数はどう規定されていて
どこのドキュメントに振る舞いが書かれているのでしょうか？

Comment: マッチする場合にのみ `{ }`(ブロック)の内部が実行されます。例えば、`'10'.match(/(100)/){ 0 / 0 }` としても `ZeroDivisionError` は発生しません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

マッチしなかった場合、ブロックは実行されません。

`ri String.match` より:

> If a block is given, invoke the block with MatchData **if match succeed**

`$1` などの変数については、`ri Regexp` (Special global variables) には以下のような記載があります。マッチさせた時点で、該当するデータが無いもの (キャプチャの括弧が1個の場合で `$2` を参照した場合など; 失敗した場合を含む) は `nil` になりますが、明確な記載は見つけられませんでした。

> $1, $2 and so on contain text matching first, second, etc capture group

Comment: ブロック自体が実行されないんですね、ありがとうございます。